Word for a type of agreement
If three people decide to go mountain climbing, and the agreement is: 'the one who gets to the top last will pay for dinner'
Is there a certain word for this type of agreement?
Can we call it a deal?
I looked up the word deal, but I'm not sure if it's the right word.
Or do we simply call it an agreement?

What exactly do you mean by this type of agreement? Does there have to be a competitive race, or is Whoever has the most money in their wallet pays for dinner the same thing? You might be looking for something like We bet on a race to the top, with the stakes being that whoever finishes last pays for dinner.

I don't know a generic term for such challenges, but the challenge The last one in is a rotten egg! has been issued countless times in the context of a group of people all about to dive in the water (especially a daunting dive, into cold sea-water).

...chatgpt suggests forfeit-based challenge, negative incentive game, race with a penalty, consequence-based game. Which are all comprehensible in context, but I don't think any of them have any currency.

ChatGPT is full of biological waste product.

@FumbleFingers a race, actually.

@TimR: It's horses for courses. Chatgpt "wants" to be helpful, so it would rather invent stuff than admit it doesn't know any such term (simply because there isn't one, imho! :). In fact, although the first and last of its suggestions drew complete blanks from Google Books, there are 2 instances of the second and the third. And if you want a hand writing your own apps, or seriously customizing your Linux home entertainment PC, it's unbelievably useful!

@FumbleFingers And for this course, ChatGPT is the wrong horse. What's a word for making stuff up when you don't know the answer?

@TimR: Given the pace of change in this area, even if your dismissal of LLMs is tenable this morning, it might be hopelessly outdated by this afternoon, so I wouldn't nail my colours too close to the mast if I were you. (As it happens, I assure you I really am writing this comment in person, but gmail already answers trivial emails, so perhaps chatgpt will offer to auto-comment on my behalf here on ELL soon! :)

If you think bureaucracy is bad, try AI.  You'll be wishing for good old bureaucrats in no time.

Unless you mean 'challenge', I suggest there is no special term for that kind of agreement.
That aside, does 'three people' matter, or would the Question mean the same with two people, or seven?
Can I be alone in thinking, where the Question came from is more interesting? What seems most likely here is, the Question comes from another language where it somehow mattered, but any real point was lost in translation…

@RobbieGoodwin It's a conversation between two guys. A group of guys are going mountain climbing early in the morning. Two of them who are roommates are talking in this conversation. One of them is waking the other up asking him to hurry. They need to get an early start because "those who get to the top last, will have to pay for dinner."
Students are asked to make questions on the conversation.
I was looking for a question the answer to which is what they have agreed to do.
As in:
A: What's the challenge/bet/deal?
B: Those who get to the top last will have to pay for dinner.

'Students are asked to make questions on the conversation' suggests the exposition is a misquotation from a lesson or text-book… and introduces at least one new query.
Being asked to ‘make’ questions is another example of a phrase wholly understandable, and acceptable in English Language Usage, but dangerously misleading in ELL
Students may be asked to ‘compose’ or ‘construct’ questions ‘about’ the conversation.
The classroom should reflect reality, where native speakers never ask students, colleagues or customers, nor generals, managers or politicians to ‘make’ questions.

The Cambridge Dictionary defines deal as

an agreement or an arrangement, especially in business

I would say that, excluding the specific case of share dealing, deal is less formal than agreement, so it is perhaps more appropriate for a situation like this.
In a situation like this, where there is a penalty/reward, you could also describe it as a bet or wager.

Cambridge can define 'deal' - or 'bet' or 'wager' - as it chooses and that won't make any of them relevant here…

@RobbieGoodwin can you provide any references to back up your claim?

No, of course not. You're asking for proof of a negative.

@RobbieGoodwin ... so  you are just stating your opinion, then.

No, of course not. What about asking for proof of a negative fails for you? We could go through the dictionary explaining why words like 'dark' or 'dim', 'dingy' mean something like 'lack of light.'
We could also explain how words unlike those don't mean the same but how long might that take? After we'd put in all that effort, what if we'd missed one single item?
That's only partly why logic won't let you get away with proving that, or any other negative.
